# View data according to class and class group

Tags: laravel

I had an admin panel where 3 types of user are there Admin, Teacher and Student. Now I want that when student logged in he/she only see data uploaded by admin

According to his/her class and class group like **class=10th** and **group=computer science**. I have no idea how can i get this type of thing. I had used following code

```
$paper = Paper::where('paper_type','PaperSolution' && 'class',Auth::user()->class)->get();
```

this is not working properly as I am dumping data

```
dd($paper);
```

it is giving me null as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you can use more granular wheres passed as array:**

```
$query->where([
    ['column_1', '=', 'value_1'],
    ['column_2', '<>', 'value_2'],
    [COLUMN, OPERATOR, VALUE],
    ...
])
```

**Try this**

```
$paper = Paper::where([['paper_type','PaperSolution'],['class', Auth::user()->class]])->get();
dd($paper);
```

**OR**

```
$paper = Paper::where([['paper_type','=','PaperSolution'],['class','=', Auth::user()->class]])->get();
dd($paper);
```

Reference for  where query using array

[ReferenceLink](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries)

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to Laravel collection docs to correct syntax.

```
$paper = Paper::where('paper_type','PaperSolution')
   ->where('class', Auth::user()->class)
   ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not exactly understand structure of your DB, but at first you need to have corresponding columns to then write any query. Your first option is `uploaded by admin` so in your uploads table (which is Paper model as I can see from your text) you should have something like `uploader_role`. Then you have `student_class` and `student_group` options. I want to get your attention in fact that this 2 options are `users` table columns NOT `uploads` (Paper). So you need to check some permissions of users, then get papers uploaded by admins. You can do that with middleware or just in your controller

```
$user = Auth::user();
if ($user->class == 10 && $user->group == 'computer_science') {
    $papers = Paper::where('uploader_role', 'admin')
    // you can add extra where options if that columns exist in papers table and you need to filter them also by class and group
    ->where( 'class_that_has_permissions', $user->class)
    ->where( 'group_that_has_permissions', $user->group)
    ->get();

    return $papers;
}

abort(404);
```

Also be careful with columns that have name `class` that can return real user class name like `App\User`, try to use `class_name` or `class_number`.